# PHP implode not add all values of database

Tags: php, mysql, explode, implode

I am in trouble and need your help.

array conversion into string only adds the last row values in implode not all.

I have following values in mysql database

Table Name: Item1

```
ID     Value
01     James,Jenny,Loreal
02     Sunny,John,Razil
```

now i want to call values from another table where names not equals to the above values. I used below query.

```
$stmt= $db->prepare("Select * from Item1");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
{
   $mark=explode(',', $row['Value']);
}

 $string_version = "'" . implode("','", $mark) . "'";

//in $string_version it only ads the 2nd row values not all rows values i need to add the all values which is in Values colunm

$stmt = $db->prepare("Select * from item2 where names not in (".$string_version.") ");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
{
echo $row['name'];
}
```

result:

```
James
Jenny
Loreal
Peter
```

result expected:

```
Peter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would follow a different path (use an array to hold all names):

```
$stmt= $db->prepare("Select * from Item1");
$stmt->execute();
$names = [];
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
{
   $mark=explode(',', $row['Value']);
   foreach ($mark as $name)
     $names[] = "'".$name."'";
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("Select * from item2 where names not in (".implode(', ', $names).") ");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
{
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Please beware this method would not work if a name contains apostrophe character (`'`). Use escaping supported by your database layer.

Answer (score 0):

`$mark` variable is not an array . That's why only "Razil" assign in that variable.

I think you need to do this :

```
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
{
   $mark[]=explode(',', $row['Value']);
}
```

Comment: ya i tried this but didnt get the result as i expect

Comment: declare $string_version as an array then use for-loop during query.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwrite $mark variable every time you loop into table item1. I suggest to write the first query with group_concat.

select group_concat(Mycol separator ', ') as names from item1